# Call and Run Ajax every X minutes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

How call and run Ajax every X minutes without the page being open (client-side), running in the background on the server side.

**My Code in Header.php:**

```
(function($) {
    function updateGo() {
        $(window).load(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/test.com/template/test/script.php',
                dataType: 'html',
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        $('body').append(data);
                    }
                }
            });
        })
    }
    updateGo();
    setTimeout(updateGo, 60 * 1000);
})(jQuery);
```

In **script.php** there are some functions and codes jquery inside and it works perfectly, but only works when I enter the page (client-side), in case I am trying to make the functions and codes of this script always run without having to enter the page.

Comment: You can't run JavaScript on the server(unless you're running Node). Try using a [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) request

Comment: sounds like you should be running a cronjob to execute the php

Comment: I'm trying run a cronjob with WP Control every 5 minutes but not achieve yet

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Call and Run Ajax every X minutes jQuery you can try the function **setInterval** [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) like:

```js
(function($) {
    function updateGo() {
        $(window).load(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/test.com/template/test/script.php',
                dataType: 'html',
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        $('body').append(data);
                    }
                }
            });
        })
    }
    updateGo();
    // for this example we take 3000 milliseconds
    let interval = 3000;
    setInterval(updateGo, interval);
})(jQuery);
```

so it's work when you load your page in your browser.

NB: in the background on the server side, we can't use Ajax, you must try to add cronJob [little documentation about](https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/)

I hope it's help you